# Laravel Mysql: Pivot table or separate model?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have this mysql database where there are two tables: `orders` & `products`.

#### Tables

```
+-------------+
|orders       |
+-------------+
|id           |
|address      |
+-------------+

+-------------+
|products     |
+-------------+
|id           |
|price        |
|qty          |
+-------------+
```

Each `Order` has multiple `items` which are `Product`. I know of two options to store this `order_item` data.

#### 1. OrderItem Model

Using this method, i'll create new eloquent model called `OrderItem` and a table called `order_items`. And create relations in the `Order` and `OrderItem` model.

```
+-------------+
|order_items  |
+-------------+
|product_id   |
|order_id     |
|price        |
|qty          |
+-------------+


// inside Order model
public function orderItems() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\OrderItem');
}

// inside OrderItem model
public function order() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Order');
}
```

#### 2. Pivot Table

Create `Order` - `Product` many to many relations.

```
+-------------+
|order_product|
+-------------+
|product_id   |
|order_id     |
|price        |
|qty          |
+-------------+

// inside Order model
public function products() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product')->withPivot('price', 'qty');
}

// inside Product model
public function orders() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order')->withPivot('price', 'qty');
}
```

Here which method is better in terms of Laravel and its code? I believe this question doesn't belong in the DBA forum because its pretty much a Laravel question. Seeking opinions of Laravel experts. Thanks for any help.

Comment: So the only difference is the name of the table. !?!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I create a separate `OrderItem` model, and store the item’s name and price at the time of purchase.

A pivot table approach has the downside that if the related product is updated or even deleted, you’re going to end up with data integrity issues.

Comment: would you add a `product_id` column to the `order_items` table?

Comment: @bazi Yeah, but I’d make it nullable in case the corresponding record in the `products` table is hard-deleted.

Answer (score -1):

The main purpose of the Pivot Tables (or manyToMany) is to solve problems like this.

And with Pivot Tables you don't even need to create separate model for this.

I'm recommending you to use Pivot Tables. It's a "correct way" in Laravel.

Comment: An example of such a relationship is a user with many roles, where the roles are also shared by other users. For example, many users may have the role of "Admin". To define this relationship, three database tables are needed: users, roles, and role_user.

Many-to-many relations requires the presence of an intermediate table. Eloquent provides some very helpful ways of interacting with this table.

[Laravel](www.laravel.com)

Comment: I understand how relationships work. I wrote a book on Laravel: https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/laravel-5-essentials. I’ve also worked on many e-commerce sites and know from experience you _shouldn’t_ relate an order directly to a product. Products change, go out of stock, etc. If the record is updated or deleted, your order line item is affected and it shouldn’t be; it should be locked in time to when the customer placed that order.

Comment: Well, good point. But that's project/function based thing to lock it or not to.